# How can I block the Internet and mobile data fallback?

Tags: ieee-802.11, internet

Hoping to block outgoing WAN access from my network during certain periods as well as stopping mobile devices from auto-failing-over to their mobile data. Of course this won't be perfect since devices could be forced to use mobile. Just trying to get a good-enough solution.

My guess is I'll need to whitelist the hosts used by the various Android and IOS devices to check for Internet when connected to Wifi. If so does anyone know what hosts are used?

Are there alternatives? (Short of installing apps on to--or directly configuring--the devices in hand)

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about host configurations are off-topic here, and you have not explained anything about the network, network devices, or network device configurations, so we cannot help with that. You could edit your question to include the necessary information. You can find guidance on the [Network Engineering Question Checklist](https://networkengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/292/8499).

Comment: This falls in the realm of an MDM -- mobile device management -- platform. While it's easy enough to cut WAN access (firewall rules), stopping mobile devices from using their mobile radios is a much harder nut.